# How to override composed struct methods in GoLang

Tags: http, oop, go, routes, overriding

I want to make a controller `struct` in GoLang that has a `ServeHTTP` method which calls its own methods (which responds with a `405` status code) based on that of the HTTP request. New controllers should be able to inherit `ServeHTTP` while also being able to override methods like `Get(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)` and have the new ones being triggered by `ServeHTTP`. Then, controllers can be assigned as route handlers with the http module. I know how to do this in Java (have a controller superclass with all basic methods), but the method overriding part fails in Go. Here is my code:

```
package main

import "net/http"

type Controller struct { }

func notAllowed(w http.ResponseWriter){
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    w.Write([]byte("405- Method Not Allowed"))
}
func(c Controller)  Get(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    notAllowed(w)
}
func(c Controller)  Post(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    notAllowed(w)   
}
func(c Controller)  Put(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    notAllowed(w)   
}
func(c Controller)  Patch(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    notAllowed(w)   
}
func(c Controller)  Delete(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    notAllowed(w)   
}
func(c Controller)  ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    switch r.Method {
        case "GET":
            c.Get(w, r)
        case "POST":
            c.Post(w, r)
        case "PUT":
            c.Put(w, r)
        case "PATCH":
            c.Patch(w, r)
        case "DELETE":
            c.Delete(w, r)
    }
}
type Index struct {
  Controller  
}
func(I Index) Get(w http.ResponseWriter, r http.Request){
  w.Write([]byte("hello"))
}
func main(){
  http.Handle("/", Index{})
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: In Go there is no inheritance, it's not your Classical OO language like Java is, and it should be of benefit to you to stop thinking in those terms when programming in Go. With that out of the way, what you can do with composition (Go's answer to inheritance), is something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/-_stPhpygW5

Comment: Right, but I don't want to write the ServeHTTP method for each new Handler.

Comment: Here's another approach: https://play.golang.org/p/U7v19vE8rt1.

Comment: @IsaacKrementsov You shouldn't have to, you only need to wrap each new controller value into a Handler value.

Comment: @IsaacKrementsov In case you haven't noticed, Controller is an interface and can be substituted in the Handler struct by anything that implements all its methods. Index does, and so this `Handler{Index{}}` is valid, you can replace `Index{}`... with anything that implements the Controller interface.

Comment: @IsaacKrementsov E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/1-LEOjTo0AX

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @mkopriva; here is the answer he put in the comments:
https://play.golang.org/p/1-LEOjTo0AX

Apparently methods will only be overriden with reverse composition.

Comment: Methods will not be overridden at all. Overriding requires inheritance, which does not exist in Go.

Comment: Right, but the methods of naController are basically being overriden by those of new controllers.

Comment: They're really not being overridden though, and thinking of it that way will lead to serious confusion in certain scenarios (eg when a method calls another method on its receiver).